# Getting a Windows service to talk to a WPF application?

Tags: c#, wpf, service

Please tell me if there is a better way to do this.

I have a WPF app, but there will be times when I need some intensive calculations to be run so I think it would be better to have this happening in its own service rather than spawning a thread to run it from the WPF app.

So here are my questions:

- How, when the WPF application is opened, can I have it so the Windows service gets opened as well? And similarly, when the application is closed the Windows service stops? It doesn't matter if it gets stopped mid-way through a calculation
- How can I get the Windows service to talk to the WPF application? I will need to get information from the Windows service... like the name of the calculation it's running, how many percent it is complete, etc, fairly basic stuff like that. But it's very important that I am able to somehow get this information out of the service so I can display it on the GUI of the WPF app.
- **An important point:** I also need a way for the GUI to talk to the Windows service. For example, I will have an area of the GUI where the user can select certain calculations that need to be processed. So I need to have a way of sending that list of selected calculations to the service, so it gets added to a queue of calculations to get run.

I have read a little bit about WCF, I haven't used it before though so I am not sure if it will be useful for what I am doing.

If anyone has any thoughts on this it would be much appreciated. It seems like a fairly simple thing to do but I'm finding no information about it - I may be search for the wrong terms though, perhaps there is a recognised name for what I am trying to do?

Thanks

Comment: Use the constructor or the window loaded event for 1.  Use WCF for communication.

Answer (score 1):

> I have a WPF app, but there will be times when I need some intensive calculations to be run so I think it would be better to have this happening in its own service rather than spawning a thread to run it from the WPF app.

In general, there is no need to do this.  Since a WPF application is already running, spawning a thread will be faster, simpler, and have less overhead than trying to start a service, use IPC to communicate with it, etc.  Just doing your calculations in your application is typically the right way to go about this.

---

That being said, I'll try to answer your questions in order:

> How, when the WPF application is opened, can I have it so the Windows service gets opened as well? And similarly, when the application is closed the Windows service stops? It doesn't matter if it gets stopped mid-way through a calculation

If you want to do this, you're better off not using a service.  A service typically has a lifetime where it starts when *Windows* starts, and shuts down when the system shuts down, and doesn't run as the user.  If you just want to launch this, just make it a normal (console) application, and use `Process.Start` to launch it.  This will also let you kill the process, if necessary via [`Process.Kill`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill.aspx).

> How can I get the Windows service to talk to the WPF application? I will need to get information from the Windows service... like the name of the calculation it's running, how many percent it is complete, etc, fairly basic stuff like that. But it's very important that I am able to somehow get this information out of the service so I can display it on the GUI of the WPF app.

This is often done by having your "service" (or application) be a [WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731082.aspx) host.  Your WPF application could then act as a client to the "service" and pass messages across using WCF.

> An important point: I also need a way for the GUI to talk to the Windows service. For example, I will have an area of the GUI where the user can select certain calculations that need to be processed. So I need to have a way of sending that list of selected calculations to the service, so it gets added to a queue of calculations to get run.

Again, making the process that you launch a WCF host will accomplish this.

That being said, unless there is a strong reason to do this, it's far simpler (and probably better) to just use threading within your application, and not worry about separate processes.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed reply, it sounds like I should be using threads. Using a simple example, if I had a class "MyCalcs" with a property "List<string> Calculations" and a few methods... RunCalculationsInOrder() (presumably what I'd be running in a new thread), GetCurrentCalculation(), GetProgress()... what would be the best way to process this in a new thread? It would obviously be more complex than this in reality, but even with this simple example I am not able to get my head around how I could pass information to (such as an updated List<string> of calcs) and from this thread.

Comment: @theqs1000 The TPL makes a lot of this fairly easy.  Take a look at http://reedcopsey.com/series/parallelism-in-net4/